# Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 88 on node.js server using mysql library

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, error-handling

I have a project in production that since users that using it, im getting the error Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 88 once in a while mostly at night times when there is no users active almost at all.

My db connection looks like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: DB_HOST,
    user: DB_USERNAME,
    database: DB_NAME,
    password: DB_PASSWORD
  });

  module.exports = {db}
```

and my DButils looks like this (some of the functions for reference):

```
getAllUsers: function getAllUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query(`SELECT * FROM users`, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(result)
        }
      })
    })
  },

  getUserID: function getUserID(phone, email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query(`SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = ? OR email = ?`, [phone, email], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(result)
        }
      })
    })
  },

  getUserInfo: function getUserInfo(phone, user_id, email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query(`SELECT id , first_name , last_name , group_id , avatar_path , first_login
      FROM users WHERE phone = ? OR email = ? OR id = ?` , [phone, email, user_id], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(result)
        }
      })
    })

  }
```

It's not the original EOF so don't pay attention to the identations.
What could be the solution for this problem?

Technical info:

- using Node.js server with express.
- using it on PM2 cluster (load balanacing) with 4 instances per environment.
- and served with NGINX.

Hope we will find a solution together :)

Thanks.